# HttpClient execution of HttpPost significantly slower on Android 3.2 than 2.3.3

Tags: android, performance, httpclient, http-post, android-3.0-honeycomb

Anyone know why the code below would run about 4 times slower on Android 3.2 (Samsung Galaxy 10.1" Tab) than it does on 2.3.3 (Motorola Droid X)?

On Android 2.3.3, the **client.execute()** call takes on average **350ms**. Under 3.2 it takes on average **1400ms**.

Also, the results are the same regardless of whether it is run in the UI thread or a background thread.

Is this an OS bug or hardware issue? Or am I not doing something right in my code? Unfortunately I can't get ADB to attach to my 3.2 virtual device, so I can't rule out hardware problems, but my gut feeling tells me this is a Honeycomb issue.

```
HttpResponse resp = null;
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> postParms = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
postParms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "test"))

try
{
    HttpPost hp = new HttpPost("http://myserver/path/method");
    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParms);
    hp.setEntity(formEntity);

    Long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    resp = client.execute(hp);
    Long stop = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    Log.i("Time = " + (stop-start) + "ms");
}
...
```

Comment: Are both requests being performed over WiFi?

Comment: Yes, both are over WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not timing anything else, install a terminal and look at `top` on the Galaxy Tab, to be sure that CPU isn't being consumed by e.g. android.process.media.

Comment: Total CPU peak only gets to 16%. And android.process.media is not even in the top 20.